# Django query to filter only first objects with particular field names

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**model**

```
class UserAction(models.Model):
    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        ("LogIn", "Entered"),
        ("LogOut", "Gone Out"),
        ("Away", "Away from Computer"),
        ("Busy", "Busy"),
        ("DoNotDisturb", "Do not disturb"),
        ("Online", "Online and Available"),
    )
    action_name = models.CharField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES, default="LogIn")
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="actions")
    action_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(), editable=False)


class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

I need to query UserAction, in such a way that I want only the last UserAction of each user. My solutions were too much time consuming. That's why looking for an optimised answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate the `Profile`s with a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Profile.objects.annotate(
    last_action=Subquery(
        UserAction.objects.filter(
            user_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-action_time').values('action_name')[:1]
    )
)
```

The `Profile`s in the queryset will have an extra attribute `.last_action` with the `action_name` of the last related `UserAction`.

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

Comment: worked perfectly.